# Applying VBA the same rule to several rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that I want to apply to several rows. I only created for Row 11, my problem is that I need to apply below code until Row 60. How can I write it?
Sorry still new in VBA world & I am having hard time understanding the `For Each` or looping rule.

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners11_Click()
    If Range("A11").Value = "new request" Then
        If Range("D11").Value = "" Or Range("E11").Value = "" Or Range("G11").Value = "" Or Range("H11").Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please fill all mandatory fields"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use data validation? You do not need VBA for this

Comment: If you still want VBA, you can use `Worksheet_Change` Event with `Intersect`. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Comment: really appreciate the input & taking time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Through Rows

### Tips

> - Use `Option Explicit` for VBA to detect errors.
> - Use constants at the beginning of the code to quickly be able to    change them in one place.
> - Declare all variables (e.g. `Dim i As Integer`)

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub RectangleRoundedCorners11_Click()

    Const cFirst As Integer = 11  ' First Row
    Const cLast As Integer = 60   ' Last Row
    Const cRequest As String = "new request"                    ' Request Text
    Const cMsg As String = "Please fill all mandatory fields"   ' MsgBox Text

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = cFirst To cLast
        If Range("A" & i).Value = cRequest Then
            If Range("D" & i).Value = "" Or Range("E" & i).Value = "" _
                Or Range("G" & i).Value = "" Or Range("H" & i).Value = "" Then
                MsgBox cMsg
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

- A one cell range can be created using Range or Cells e.g. for `A1`:
  `Range("A1")` or `Cells(1, "A")` or `Cells(1, 1)`.
- The `If` statement has a few versions. In this case two of them are
  equally valid, simplified as follows:

---

```
    If x=y Then
        x=5
    End If

    ' or 

    If x=y Then x=5
```

### A More Advanced Version

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners11_Click()

    Const cFirst As Integer = 11  ' First Row
    Const cLast As Integer = 60   ' Last Row
    Const cRequest As String = "new request"                    ' Request Text
    Const cMsg As String = "Please fill all mandatory fields"   ' MsgBox Text
    Const cColumns As String = "A,D,E,G,H"                      ' Columns List

    Dim vnt As Variant  ' Columns Array
    Dim i As Integer    ' Row Counter

    vnt = Split(cColumns, ",")  ' An array created with Split is 0-based.

    For i = cFirst To cLast
        If Cells(i, vnt(0)).Value = cRequest Then
            If Cells(i, vnt(1)).Value = "" Or Cells(i, vnt(2)).Value = "" _
                    Or Cells(i, vnt(3)).Value = "" _
                    Or Cells(i, vnt(4)).Value = "" Then MsgBox cMsg
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Code below:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners11_Click()
  for i=11 to 60
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "new request" Then
        If Range("D" & i).Value = "" Or Range("E" & i).Value = "" Or Range("G" & i).Value = "" Or Range("H" & i).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please fill all mandatory fields"
        End If
    End If
  next i
End Sub
```

This will check the rows between 11 and 60. If you need more rows, just edit the values in the for statement.

Comment: really thank you, you code made it really simple and easy to understand,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners11_Click()
        Dim col As Integer
        If Range("A11").Value = "new request" Then
            'loop from D to ...
            For col = 4 To 60
                If Range(Col2Letter(col) & "11").Value = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Please fill all mandatory fields"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Function Col2Letter(lngCol As Integer) As String
        Dim vArr
        vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
        Col2Letter = vArr(0)
    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to provide answer, really appreciate it a lot.